# Convert Excel file to JSON: design of JSON code check

Tags: javascript, sql, json, excel, d3.js

I want to convert the data from an Excel file to a JSON file. However, I'm not sure about the design of my JSON code (i.e. is it organized in a proper way in order to process it easily?)
I will use this JSON file with D3.js.

This a small part of my Excel file:

[image]

I'd like to convert this data into a JSON file in order to use it with D3.js. This is what I have so far:

[image]

So my question is: **is this a good design (way) for organizing the data in order to use it with D3.js?**
This is a sample output:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally, I would convert it to CSV and then use the built-in functions in d3 (d3.nest) to massage into the best shape for processing and visualising.  You could also do an intermediate step and convert to CSV, load into D3, and then write the resulting JSON object to a file for future use.  I'd also agree with using the structure proposed by meetamit, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat subjective question, but from my experience, there is a better way:

Since you're working in d3, you're probably doing something like this:

```
d3.selectAll('div')
  .data(entities)
.enter()
  .append('div')
  ...
```

So you want `entities` to be an array. The question is what are your entities? Is there a view where entities are all the countries in the world? Is there a view where entities are all the countries plus all the regions plus the whole world? Or, are all the views going to be simply all the countries in a selected region, not including the region itself?

The unless the JSON structure you're proposing matches the combinations of entities that you plan to display, your code will have to do a bunch of concat'ing and/or filtering of arrays in order to get a single entities array that you can bind to. Maybe that's ok, but it will create some unnecessary amount of coupling between your code and the structure of the data.

From my experience, it turns out that the most flexible way (and also probably the simplest in terms of coding) is to keep the hierarchy flat, like it is in the excel file. So, instead of encoding regions into the hierarchy, just have them in a single, flat array like so:

```
{
  "immigration": [
    {
      "name": "All Countries"
      "values: [
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Africa"
      "values: [
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Eastern Africa"
      "continent": "Africa"
      "values": [
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Burundi"
      "continent": "Africa"
      "region": "East Africa"
      "values": [
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Djibouti"
      "continent": "Africa"
      "region": "East Africa"
      "values": [
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        { "Year": ..., "value": ... },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Note that even though the array is flat, there is still a hierarchy here -- the `region` and `sub-region` properties.

You'll have to do a bit of filtering to extract just the countries/regions you want to show. But that's simpler than traversing the hierarchy you're proposing:

```
var africanEntities = data.immigration.filter(function(country) {
  return country.continent == "Africa";
}); // Includes the region "East Africa"

var justCountries = data.immigration.filter(function(country) {
  return country.continent != null && country.region != null;
});
```

Also, d3 has the awesome [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest), which lets you turn this flat data into hierarchical one with little effort:

```
var countriesByContinent = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.continent; })
  .map(data.immigration);

var africanEntities = countriesByContinent['Africa'];
```

Hope that helps....